# Win7 hung on update

Tags: windows-7

Following other threads regarding Win7 hung on update. However, unable to get into safe mode. Appears keyboard is not funtioning when rebooting. Is there another way to break the update loop?

Comment: More details on the problem please, and exactly what it does when you boot. You did not give use much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling "USB Emulation" in your BIOS and see if that allows the keyboard to work in Safe Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too new to post comments, apparently. So here goes: I'm assuming this is a desktop with a USB keyboard. It's possible that your BIOS doesn't recognize the keyboard. In which case, check to see if your computer has PS/2 ports (They're round and colored green/purple).

If your computer has those ports, try rounding up a PS/2 keyboard and plugging it in. It may help.

Alternatively, you can take a gamble that the boot order places the optical drive over the hard drive and try booting into a Linux Live CD (just to get access to files).